# Retrieve all Facebook access tokens of an app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-access-token

I have never stored Facebook access token of users, but now I need them so I can start publishing on thier behalf.
Is there a way through Facebook's app management interface, to retrieve all the access tokens of users ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not.

You can only generate user access tokens by having users visit your app/website again – if you embed the JS SDK, it will give you an access token automatically; otherwise (server-side) you will have to send them through the login flow again to generate one.

Comment: Thank you I'll set a storing system for these tokens!